# Open Camera Inside Fragment OnActivityResult not getting called

Tags: android

I am trying to open camera inside fragment camera is opened but onActivityResult is not calling. I am not getting why it's not getting called. so if any one have an idea please share with me.

Thanks,
Murali.

Comment: please enclose a [MCVE], the Manifest, and logcat.

Answer (score 0):

You may have "launchMode="singleInstance" in your activity in Android Manifest.
Also make sure you call your activity with startActivityForResult() method.